# Accessing attributes referenceId in REST API Composite call

Tags: rest-api, composite

I am writing a composite call to create products and add them to strandard Pricebook.

```
{
   "allOrNone":true,
   "collateSubrequests":false,
   "compositeRequest":[
      {
         "method":"GET",
         "referenceId":"refProductRecordType",
         "url":"/services/data/v56.0/query/?q=SELECT+id+FROM+RecordType+WHERE+SobjectType+='Product2'+AND+DeveloperName+='Product'"
      },
      {
         "method":"PATCH",
         "referenceId":"refProdList",
         "url":"/services/data/v56.0/composite/sobjects/Product2/External_Id__c",
         "body":{
            "allOrNone":true,
            "records":[
               {
                  "attributes":{
                     "type":"Product2",
                     "referenceId":"prod0"
                  },
                  "RecordTypeId":"@{refProductRecordType.records[0].Id}",
                  "Name":"product 1",
                  "External_Id__c":"12121",
                  "Description":"bla bla",
                  "IsActive":true
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "method":"GET",
         "referenceId":"refPricebook",
         "url":"/services/data/v56.0/query/?q=SELECT+id+FROM+Pricebook2+WHERE+Name+='Standard Price Book'+AND+IsStandard+=+true"
      },
      {
         "method":"POST",
         "referenceId":"refPbe",
         "url":"/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/PricebookEntry",
         "body":{
            "Pricebook2Id":"@{refPricebook.records[0].Id}",
            "Product2Id":"@{prod0.Id}",
            "UnitPrice":0.00,
            "IsActive":true
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

When I try executing this composite POST call, I get error :

```
{
   "body":[
      {
         "errorCode":"PROCESSING_HALTED",
         "message":"Could not find the referenced operation prod0"
      }
   ],
   "httpHeaders":{
      
   },
   "httpStatusCode":400,
   "referenceId":"refPbe"
}
```

I am trying to access the referenceId "prod0", but not sure how to get it because it's kind of a nested reference.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @identigral : here the question is about accessing PATCH request reference Id and your states  GET request. If we observe this question, GET request Id is already used for pricebooks.

Comment: There is no way for me to know if below answer solves the question. This is a serious limitation which will hamper the usability of Q&A on this site when anyone refers this in the future.

Comment: @Rohit Is this because your answer wasn't accepted or...?

Comment: @identigral : Accepting answer is half part of the problem. The other half is if someone refers this question in the future , how will he/she come to know if below answer helps or not? If there are multiple answers , it will add to the confusion of which one is right?
Last time I had politely asked the author to accept the answer if it helps but then one of the moderators termed it as "begging". :)
In my opinion , moderators should have the right to accept the answer if the question author does not.

Comment: @Rohit Keep answering, you'll get more acceptance. We've upvoted your answer, it's good.

Comment: @identigral : Sure, will keep answering regardless of acceptance  Thank you.

Comment: Upvoted the question too. For a first question, it was well-formatted and had enough detail for Rohit to provide a correct answer. Welcome to Salesforce SE, @Shilpa Vashishtha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is seen since we cannot assign reference id to individual objects in request.

Reference Id is on sub-request level.
To fix this , you need to set `Product2Id` as below. We refer to the 1st record of the PATCH sub request :

```
"Product2Id": "@{refProdList[0].Id}"
```

Here , `refProdList` refers to the PATCH request for `Product2`.

More info can be found in this documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/requests_composite.htm